# Profound Grid cannot find clearfix

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, fluid-layout, profound-grid

So I'm designing a website and I stumbled upon a nice tool for fluid design called Profound Grid. http://www.profoundgrid.com/

I thought it would be very useful and decided to use it, but I find the documentation is meagre at best, and there is little to no help around the internet, the website doesn't even have a contact us button...

The website said that the Profound Grid was created and is used with SASS.

I've installed ruby and SASS successfully and am able to use them just fine, but when I try to use the Profound Grid; which is done by importing a file into your style sheet, the SASS converter gives me an error:

> error grid/_grid.scss (Line23: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/utilities/general/clearfix.)

The Profound Grid system uses only one file to function, which is imported into your style sheet, and that is the "_grid.scss", I opened it and found this on the 23rd line:

> @import "compass/utilities/general/clearfix";

It appears the grid system imports and uses a file from compass...

To fix this problem I installed the compass gem but I still get the same error message, it cannot locate the clearfix file even though I should have it installed.

To test my compass installation I tried just importing compass like this:

> @import 'compass';

An error came up telling me that compass couldn't be located either, so I think there might be something wrong with me compass installation or the way I am importing it.

Have I installed compass wrong?

Is there something wrong with the way compass is being imported? Perhaps the wrong path?

If there is anyone out there with experience with Compass, SASS or Profound Grid I would much appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you using the `compass` command?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`compass`](http://compass-style.org/) command-line tool to compile it. For example:

```
compass compile
```

Strange that this piece of software is not distributed as a Compass extension.